# No retorna valor con mutators en laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, model

Tengo el siguiente problema al utilizar mutadores para poder generar un valor que se inserte a la base de datos:

Mi modelo cuenta con un campo llamado `order` el encargado de llevar la posición de un menú, cuando genero un nuevo menú quiero que consulte `max('order')` e incrementar `+1`.

Mutator

```
public function setOrderAttribute($value)
{
     $query = $this->where('parent', '0')->max('order');
     $this->attributes['order'] = $query + 1;
}
```

Nota: Probé realizando otro mutador con **Nombre** y si funciono, solo cuando manejo enteros no me agrega el valor que necesito, también probé con

```
$this->attributes['order'] = 20;
```

y nada.

¿Qué estoy realizando mal?

Saludos

UPDATE: El modelo

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Sluggable;

    protected $table = 'int_menu';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_menu';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];  
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'icono', 'parent', 'order', 'id_page'];
    protected $casts = ['order' => 'integer'];


    public function page()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Intranet\Page' ,'id_page');
    }

    public function getChildren($data, $line)
    {
        $children = [];
        foreach ($data as $line1) {
            if($line['id_menu'] == $line1['parent']) {
                $children = array_merge($children,
                                            [array_merge($line1,
                                                ['submenu' => $this->getChildren($data, $line1)
                                                ])
                                            ]);             
            }
        }
        return $children;
    }

    public function optionsMenu()
    {
        return $this->where('enabled', 1)
            ->orderby('parent')
            ->orderby('order')
            ->orderby('nombre')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
    }

    public static function menus()
    {
        $menus = new Menu();
        $data = $menus->optionsMenu();
        $menuAll = [];
        foreach ($data as $line) {
            $item = [ array_merge($line, ['submenu' => $menus->getChildren($data, $line) ]) ];
            $menuAll = array_merge($menuAll, $item);
        }
        return $menus->menuAll = $menuAll;
    }

    public function setOrderAttribute($value)
    {
        /*$query = $this->where('parent', '1')
                        ->max('order');*/
        //$this->attributes['nombre'] = Hash::make($value);
        $this->attributes['order'] = 1;     
    }

    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'nombre'
            ]           
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Falta una comilla en el código; quizá sea eso `$this->attributes['order]`, aunque debería dar error:

```
public function setOrderAttribute($value)
{
     $query = $this->where('parent', '0')->max('order');
     if(!$query){
         $query=0;
     }
     $this->attributes['order'] = $query + 1;
}
```

Por otro lado si la búsqueda que realizas primero devuelve null ... Tendría que ver el modelo..

Comment: si tiene la comilla solo que cuando genere el post la quito, y por lo siguiente  si le pongo un número entero cualquiera tampoco lo hace, como lo expongo en la última parte: $this->attributes['order'] = 20;

Comment: Entonce necesito que pongas el código del modelo para poder ayudarte. Yo he estado haciendo pruebas y tal y cómo lo pones (con la cmilla :-) ) funciona con cadenas y números.

Comment: Hola, acabo de agregar el modelo.

Comment: Debes verificar que la consulta no está devolviendo null. Si devuelve null no te funcionará. He hecho una pequeña modificación en la respuesta; prueba con ella.

Comment: Ya vi cual es mi problema, se encuentra en la migración, que tengo: $table->smallInteger('order')->default(0); tengo que quitar default(0) probando con tinker pude generar un nuevo objeto y me da el valor del mutador.

Comment: El problema ahora es que este valor no lo paso en el formulario y me manda el siguiente errro: General error: 1364 Field 'order' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `int_menu` (`nombre`, `icono`, `parent`, `id_page`, `slug`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Prueba 1, fa fa-close, 0, , prueba-1, 2017-11-27 16:46:03, 2017-11-27 16:46:03)) por que no tiene valor por default y si agrego el valor por default a la migración o al modelo ya no toma en cuenta el mutador.

Comment: La única solución que encuentro es generar el campo en la vista, de tipo oculto, que opinas @Pedro Prada, saludos

Comment: En caso de que esto sea el problem, lo que puedes hacer es que el campo acepte nulos (En la migración pon "->nullable()" ). Así no te pedirá un valor por defecto.

Comment: Gracias @Pedro Padra , tampoco funciono tengo que mandar el valor por default desde la vista para que haga el cálculo, ya que si lo pongo en el modelo o la migración no toma en cuenta el mutador, lo dejare así mientras. Gracias por el apoyo  saludos.